# How to setup Twilio.Device with new token?

Tags: javascript, token, twilio, destroy

By default all tokens generated with the Twilio helper libraries expire after one hour. But you should configure this expiration to be as short as possible for your application.

I am trying to generate a new token each time a user attempts a new connection and try to setup Twilio device. But it creates new device each time. So all Twilio device get incoming call and i can see multiple notification for that. Multiple connections created an dmultiple dtmf sent. I want only one twilio device with fresh token.

`Twilio.Device.destroy()` method is there but it is not working. What are other option do I have?
How to release/destroy/stop/delete Twilio.Device?

After saving credentials `globalTwilioSagaSetup()` called and after 58min of that again token is generated and Twilio.Device setup is done.

```
function globalTwilioSagaSetup()
{
    // Get Twilio credentials

    // Get Twilio Token

    // Setup Twilio Device

    // For token re-generation before expire. 58min
    setInterval(function(){globalTwilioSagaSetup();},3480000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue although in current version of twilio lib (i.e. 1.2). The thing is that once `setup` is called `ready` event is fired but only after first call to the `setup` method. It means that even if one will initialize device with new token there will be problems with establishing new connection. Therefore calling `Twilio.Device.destroy()` then `setup` and then connect (via `ready` event) solved that issue for me. Here is an example:

```
    srv.connectToTwilio = () => $q((resolve, reject) => {
        var connection;

        try {
            connection = Twilio.Device.connect();
        } catch (err) {
            $log.debug('Device.connect(): throw', err);
        }

        if (connection) {
            try {
                connection.accept(() => {
                    $log.debug(`Twilio connection.accept.`);
                    resolve();
                });
            } catch (err) {
                $log.debug('connection.accept(): throw', err);
            }

        } else {
            reject(`Device.connect() did not return connection`);
        }
    });

    srv.connect = (token) => {
        return srv.setToken(token).then(() => srv.connectToTwilio());
    };

    srv.disconnect = () => {
        shouldBeConnected = false;
        try {
            Twilio.Device.activeConnection().disconnect();
        } catch (error) {
            $log.debug(error);
        } finally {
            Twilio.Device.destroy();
        }
        $log.debug(`Twilio disconnect.`);
    };
```

Comment: @Gino I've updated my answer with code which should give you an idea. AFAIR not all methods used by me were documented (particularly destroy method)